# How does DotNetNuke Hash Its Passwords?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I am writing a login system that will log in against a DotNetNuke application's database.  I have access to the database and can read the PasswordSalt in the aspnet_Membership table.  Hence I will have as inputs:

1. user's password (submitted by form)
2. user's salt (I can look up)

and I must produce as output the hashed Password.  The PasswordFormat=2, which is "Encrypted".  However, I have not been able to find details of the encryption algorithm being used, so that I can rewrite it in my own application.  So far, my research has led be to this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478949.aspx

and also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8132734/438615), which has the following formula in one of the comments:

```
Convert.ToBase64String((new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(YourPWD, YourSALT)).GetBytes(20))
```

However, this formula does not appear to work on my test data, which has the following inputs and outputs:

1. password: 888888
2. salt: ahEvjCX3FM04S5cSi1qdHA==
3. hashed password: y3rxLUDYdj1/+IGC94/tvW6M3pQTCi/9bq1cNOUgYlM=

You can see my test here: http://ideone.com/EClO2

```cs
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
 
public class Test
{
        public static void Main()
        {
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String((new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("888888", System.Convert.FromBase64String("ahEvjCX3FM04S5cSi1qdHA=="))).GetBytes(20)));
        }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

## UPDATE

Answered here: [ASP.NET MembershipProvider -- How exactly does it do encryption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433726/asp-net-membershipprovider-how-exactly-does-it-do-encryption)

Comment: `Encryption` is not `Hashing`, you will need to generate a encrypted version (maybe try triple DES)

Comment: Can you be more specific.  I tried applying triple DES to both "pw + hash" and "hash + pw", and base64 encoding the result, and it did not match.  I need to know exactly what DNN is doing internally.

Comment: I meant Triple DES is type of encryption try that instead of `Base64`

Comment: Base64 is just an encoding.  Salts and hashes are usually encoded that way so they are more readable.  In any case, if you have a specific idea, please post the code you'd like me try.  Thanks.

Comment: From what I've read, DNN uses the [`SqlMembershipProvider class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx). You can use that to decrypt the password. I would recommend actually hashing it. [Read this](http://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2010/12/31/keeping-user-passwords-secure-in-dotnetnuke.aspx)

Comment: This was answered [in this post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433726/asp-net-membershipprovider-how-exactly-does-it-do-encryption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code, they have a class called `AspNetMembershipProvider` which has a method called `UserLogin`. `UserLogin` calls a private method called `ValidateUser` which in turn uses the ASP.NET Membership provider so it actually calls this method [Membership.ValidateUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.validateuser.aspx) internally.

So if you call the same method with the username and password, the membership provider will take care of the password hashing and return a boolean value indicating whether the password matches.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  So is the salt not used at all in this process?  I actually need to get the hashed value, not just the boolean of if it matches or not.  The new application I'm writing is in ruby, so I need to be able to duplicate whatever logic ValidateUser is doing -- where can I find the source for that?

Comment: I've done more research and discovered that the actual encryption/decryption is handled by [MembershipProvider.EncryptPassword and DecryptPassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.encryptpassword.aspx).  So really I just need to find the source code of those methods, but I haven't been able to do so yet....

Comment: @Jonah where is deCrypt method?

Comment: @Jonah, did you get this to work? I have the same task with something else and I'm out of options, perhaps your solution will work with me.

Comment: @DanChase, No, I never did, but that's not to say it won't.  Ended up not needing it for other reasons.